# Proving that the function of a sequence must be some value

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions

Suppose we have a continuous differentiable function $f: (a, b) \to \mathbb{R}$, and a sequence $(s_n)_n$ of unique points in $(a, b)$ converging to some $s \in (a, b)$. If $f(s_n) = 0 \; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, how would I go about showing that $f(s) = 0$ as well?

My thoughts were to at first use the fact that the zero sets of continuous functions are closed, which would be contradicted if $f(s)$ were not 0. However, I feel like there is a better way to go about this using the properties of sequences—I just can't seem to come up with it for some reason. If anyone could offer some advice, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where you say 'open', do you mean 'non closed'?. For example, the set $\{1/n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is not open or closed.

Comment: @ajotatxe Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple application of the fact that for any (real-valued) continuous function $f$, we have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} f(s_n) = f\left(\lim_{n \to \infty }s_n\right).
$$

Comment: Continuous $f$ with codomain a Hausdorff space.

Comment: @DanielH.Hartman Is a Hausdorff codomain really a requirement here? Do you have a counterexample to the general statement off the top of your head?

Comment: Wow cannot believe that property didn't come to mind. Thank you.

Comment: @DanielH.Hartman It seems that there is nothing special about the fact that $f$ has a Hausdorff codomain. In fact, [every continuous function is sequentially continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Sequences_and_nets), but the converse might fail to hold if the codomain fails to be first countable or if we forego the axiom of countable choice.

Comment: @BenGrossmann
Take the line with two origins. let $f$ be the inclusion of $\mathbb{R}$. This is continuous. Take $s_n$ converging to zero. What does $f(s_n)$ converge to? It has two different limit points. One of which is f(0), but the other isn't. So, point is that you have lim f(s_n) converging to a unique thing f(lim(s_n)). That's false

Comment: @BenGrossmann Now you can avoid this by just saying "any continuous real valued functions"

Comment: @DanielH.Hartman I see, so it is true that $f(s_n)$ converges to $f(0)$ (i.e. that $f$ is "sequentially continuous"), but it is not true that $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(s_n)$ is well-defined as an element of the codomain. Thanks for that example